# Memsql Master Node is not running

Tags: singlestore

I have a memsql cluster with 1 master and 4 leaf node.
I have a problem my **master node is not running** but it is connected in the cluster. And i can read and write a data to my cluster.
while trying to restart the master node its showing some error.

```
2018-03-31 20:54:22: Jb2ae955f6 [ERROR] Failed to connect to MemSQL node BD60BED7C8082966F375CBF983A46A9E39FAA791: ProcessHandshakeResponsePacket() failed. Sending back 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: NO)
ProcessHandshakeResponsePacket() failed. Sending back 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'10.254.34.135' (using password: NO)
```

Cluster status

```
Index  ID                Agent Id  Process State  Cluster State  Role    Host           Port  Version
 1      BD60BED           Afb08cd   NOT RUNNING    CONNECTED      MASTER  10.254.34.135  3306  5.8.10
 2      D84101F           A10aad5   RUNNING        CONNECTED      LEAF    10.254.42.244  3306  5.8.10
 3      3D2A2AF           Aa2ac03   RUNNING        CONNECTED      LEAF    10.254.38.76   3306  5.8.10
 4      D054B1C           Ab6c885   RUNNING        CONNECTED      LEAF    10.254.46.99   3306  5.8.10
 5      F8008F7           Afb08cd   RUNNING        CONNECTED      LEAF    10.254.34.135  3307  5.8.10
```

Answer (score 2):

That error means that while the node is online, memsql-ops is unable to log in to the node, most likely because the root user's password is misconfigured somewhere in the system - memsql-ops is configured with no password for that node, but likely the memsql node does have a root password set.

Did you set a root password in memsql? Are you able to connect to the master node directly via mysql client?

If yes, you can fix this by logging in to the memsql master node directly and changing the root password to blank:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' identified by '' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Then, after ensuring that connectivity is restored, you can update the root password in the future with the command https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-ops-cli-reference/v6.0/memsql-update-root-password/.

Comment: Thanks, but i already try this command. Its not working for me, can you help to solve this.

Comment: What was the result - what did the command output? And what are the answers to: Did you set a root password in memsql? Are you able to connect to the master node directly via mysql client?

Comment: Same error only its showing, yes i already set the password, i can access the memsql directly form the terminal.

Comment: So are you saying you are able to log in with no password? Because the error above is from trying to log in without a password. Make sure you change all the root users (there might be multiple). If that still doesn't work, it's hard to help over stackoverflow, please submit a support ticket if you are a customer.